# Removing ' null, not set or "" ' items from a list

Tags: sesam

I'm trying to remove `null`, `not set`, `""` values from a list. Abeit I can't seem to find a solution/function that solves this problem.

Use Case:

- A client wanting an output stripped of any kind of null values.

Tried a bunch of different functions i.e. strip, replace, if, neq ...

pipe config

```
{
  "_id": "jonas-testing",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "1",
      "list": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["add", "_this-is-a-list-for-testing",
          ["list", "foo", "", "bar", "baz"]
        ],
        ["add", "list-with-no-nulls",
          ["if",
            ["eq", "_T._this-is-a-list-for-testing", ""],
            ["strip", "", "_T._this-is-a-list-for-testing"],
            ["strip", "", "_T._this-is-a-list-for-testing"]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "_this-is-a-list-for-testing": [
      "foo",
      "",
      "bar",
      "baz"
    ],
    "list": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    "list-with-no-nulls": [
      "foo",
      "",
      "bar",
      "baz"
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "_this-is-a-list-for-testing": [
      "foo",
      "",
      "bar",
      "baz"
    ],
    "list": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    "list-with-no-nulls": [
      "foo",
      "bar",
      "baz"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "filter" function with "is-not-null" or "neq" to filter out null values or empty string values:

```
{
  "_id": "jonas-testing",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "1",
      "list": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "*"],
        ["add", "_this-is-a-list-for-testing",
          ["list", "foo", "", "bar", "baz"]
        ],
        ["add", "list-with-no-empty-strings",
            ["filter", ["neq", "", "_."], "_T._this-is-a-list-for-testing"]
        ],
        ["add", "list-with-no-nulls",
            ["filter", ["is-not-null", "_."], "_T._this-is-a-list-for-testing"]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Solved the issue, albeit ´´´["filter", ["is-not-null", "_."]...´´´did not seem to work.

Comment: ```is-not-null``` worked fine for me. The example doesn't contain any nulls, but if you add a null to ```_this-is-a-list-for-testing``` list it will be removed from the ```list-with-no-nulls``` property.

Comment: Okay, might be a typo because I tried doing that as well. But thanks a lot anyways!